# Redux - Does initialState need to be an object in createSlice()?

Tags: redux, react-redux, immer.js

This code below throws an error when I dispatch:

```js
// countSlice.js
const countSlice = createSlice({
    name: "count",
    initialState: 0,
    reducers: {
        add(state) {state += 1},
    },
});
```

However if I change `initialState` into an object, the code works fine:

```js
// countSlice.js
const countSlice = createSlice({
    name: "count",
    initialState: {value: 0}, // now it works!
    reducers: {
        add(state) {state.value += 1},
    },
});
```

The code also works if I keep `initialState` as a number, but write the reducer as an array function:

```js
// countSlice.js
const countSlice = createSlice({
    name: "count",
    initialState: 0,
    reducers: {
        add: state => state + 1, // also works!
    },
});
```

I'm just learning Redux and got confused by this. Does this have something to do with Immer? Did I make a mistake with the reducer function?

Comment: It should work since they're doing the exact same thing in the official docs. Which error are you getting?

Comment: @timotgl `Uncaught Error: A case reducer on a non-draftable value must not return undefined` from `createReducer.ts`

Comment: Upon closer inspection of the docs, it looks like they're handling the state differently. With `reducers: { nameOfAction(state) { // mutate state }}` the state is expected to be an object. With `reducers: { nameOfAction: state => state + 1}` the state can be anything. It's a subtle difference and the example in the docs maybe a bit misleading. In real apps, the state is rarely a singular value, that wouldn't be very useful.

Comment: I see. Then I'll just declare it as an object, that seems like the better practice anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why

```
const countSlice = createSlice({
    name: "count",
    initialState: 0,
    reducers: {
        add(state) {state += 1},
    },
});
```

doesn't work, is because your add reducer isn't actually returning anything. This is fine if the state is an object, because objects are mutable. But if your state is just an integer, then you need to return it to actually update the state, as integers are immutable.

Answer (score 0):

You simply return the state itself if you want to set initial state as a value and not an object

const idSlice = createSlice({
name: "idSlice",
initialState: "",
reducers: {
setId(state, action) {
state = action.payload;
return state;
},
},
});

I did this, works for me